# How can we generate different type catalog images as per the different category in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

By default, Woocommerce have following thumbnails sizes:

300x300 (Single product) /* 300px is set by mine, i am not remember exactly what is default size but, is similar */

120x120 (Gallery - Categories - Archive Page - Search products)

90x90 (Thumbnails in single product)

But as per my requirement i need different catalog size like (Default catalog image=>120x120, Shirt image=>120x250 and Suit image=> 150x352,).

can anyone please tell me how to make each category has different sized thumbnails please?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer of my question:

Write down the below code in function.php file of your theme:

```
add_image_size('catalog_image2', 120, 250, true);
add_image_size('catalog_image3', 150, 352, true)
```

It will crop the product image while uploading the product images and you can call those images on catalog page.

You can see those images under wp-content\uploads\ folder.

Comment: To call this image on catalog page:

$image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id()));

$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'catalog_image2', 'catalog_image2' ), array('title' => $image_title ));

echo apply_filters( 'catalog_image2', sprintf( '%s', $image ), $post->ID );